# Where is Typescript project in visual studio 2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm dealing with this for several days, and still find no answer

I installed the typescript tool for visual studio 2015, and it shows that it is installed.
[image]

However, there is no typescript project here, my visual studio is update 3

[image]

what should I do to get the Typescript project?

Answer (score 0):

```
New Project => Installed => TypeScript
```

however please note that you need to add TypeScript feature from `Tools => Get Tools And Features`

[image]

Comment: there is no Typescript project in New project just like what I showed in the picture and I have even no Get Tools and Features in my Tools menu...